# How to get Max id From Database using c#?

Tags: c#

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT max(substr(tr_refno,9,6))as REFID from ECHALLAN WHERE DEPT='" +tmpDept.ToString() + "' and substr(tr_refno,5,2) ='" + Tmpmonth + "'", con);                         
maxid = Convert.ToInt16( cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

> Error= InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code

Comment: your data types are invalid so be sure that whatever the data type for max(substr(tr_refno, 9, 6)) is matches the .NET type. also be sure to check that the value is coming back....

Comment: Before Convert it. You could first check the nullity.

Comment: What is the result of the `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` looks like when you debug it? And please use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Beware of SQL Injection! The way you just concatenate your parameter values to your query is a bar open to injections, which consists of a big security flaw. Use **`IDataParameter`** : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idataparameter(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Before Converting it you could check the nullity:

```
var value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
int maxI;
If(value !=null)
   maxId = Convert.ToInt32(value);
else 
//......................
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Max(COALESCE(substr(tr_refno,9,6),0)) as REFID from ECHALLAN WHERE DEPT='" +tmpDept.ToString() + "' and substr(tr_refno,5,2) ='" + Tmpmonth + "'", con);
```